# How to detect Oreo colored playback notification text color

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to implement Android O colored playback notification. Part of notification uses custom view with title, subtitle and custom progress 
(`builder.setCustomContentView(notificationViews);
builder.setCustomBigContentView(notificationViewsExpanded);`) what results in not tinting of these custom views ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hShY0.jpg)).

Is it possible to detect what color will be used for notification text so I can set it programmatically for custom views?

Do anybody know algorithm used by android for parsing of this color from artwork?

Comment: Generated notification has color field: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#color

Comment: is that possible in javascript? i am also finding this text and bg color algorithm.